# Having indentation errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is with the following code here:

```
import wget
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json
import codecs
import os
import os.path
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time
import datetime

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1M9tgEZqKMihgnYO33GvTQ/videos"

browser.get(url)
video = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]')
video_title = str(video.text)
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    past_title = data["title"]

if past_title == video_title:
    print("Don't post")
    l_updated=data["last_updated"]
    print("Lastest video upload was on " + l_updated)
else: 
    video.click()

    video_link = str(browser.current_url)
    video_id = video_link.split("=", 1)[1]
browser.quit()
group = ['100003333789620']

time.sleep(5)

pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyDown('t')
pyautogui.keyUp('t')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')

for i in range(len(group)):
    link = 'https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/'+group[i]
    pyautogui.typewrite(link)
    pyautogui.typewrite('\n')

    print("Waiting for 10 seconds\n")
    time.sleep(10)

    pyautogui.moveTo(2034, 699, 4)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Writing message about the new uploaded lecture\n")
    pyperclip.copy("Христо's Bot reporting for duty! Новата лекция е качена тук " +video_link)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
    time.sleep(4)

    pyautogui.keyDown('enter')
    pyautogui.keyUp('enter')
    print("Message was successfully sent!")
    time.sleep(2)

    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyDown('w')
    pyautogui.keyUp('w')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    print("Closing the tab now and storing data!")



data["title"]=video_title
data["last_updated"]=str(datetime.date.today())
with open("data.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
time.sleep(5)
```

The problem is that i want to put everything after `video_link = str(browser.current_url) video_id = video_link.split("=", 1)[1]` in the else statement but i keep getting indentation errors. The code works but it doesn't check if the the video title exists in the json file (i tried encoding it to utf-8 because the video titles are in cyrillic. It encodes it but it doesn't want to read from it for some weird reason and it threw some charmap error that i couldn't fix)

Comment: charmap is a type of encoder. You should change that. I think you failed to change it to utf-8

Comment: Can you send the full error message pls?

Comment: Regarding your indentation, you're mixing tabs and spaces. Use a proper IDE which converts that for you. Such an IDE will also tell you that you use `video_link` but you have defined `link` only.

Comment: Try PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Comment: The char map error was the following 
"'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 20: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Also, doesn't matter if i use TAB or 4 spaces, it always throws "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"
I use VS Code but i will try PyCharm for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Quick update!

I managed to fix it like this

```
with open("data.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

And

```
with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
data = json.load(f)
```

I was probably overthinking it.
PyCharm fixed the indentations too.

Thanks for all the help guys!